# Laravel @foreach Repeating

Tags: laravel, foreach

when I am trying to add @foreach 3 times it's repeating my data. how do I solve this?

this is my code

> My Controller

```
$students = Student::with('FeeScheem','IndFeeScheem','FeeGroup','FeeGroup1')
->where('students.stu_id', $students)
->get();
$this->students = $students;
```

> Eloquent Relationship

```
public function FeeScheem()
        {
            return $this->hasOne(FeeScheem::class, 'fs_id', 'stu_fee_scheem_id'); 
        }

        public function IndFeeScheem()
        {
            return $this->hasOne(IndividuallyFeeScheem::class, 'id', 'stu_ind_fee_scheem_id');
        }

        public function FeeGroup()
        { 
            return $this->hasManyThrough(FeeMaster::class, FeeGroups::class);        
        }

        public function FeeGroup1()
        { 
            return $this->hasMany(FeeGroups::class, 'individually_fee_scheem_id', 'stu_fee_scheem_id');        
        }
```

> My Blade File

```
@foreach ($students as $stu=>$student)
    @foreach ($student->FeeGroup as $key=>$FeeG)
  
    @foreach ($student->FeeGroup1 as $key1=>$FeeG1)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
      <td>{{ $FeeG1->fee_group_name }}</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach 
    @endforeach 
    @endforeach 
  </tbody>
```

> This is a preview

[Click here to preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vURhY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `index` property of the [loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable) :

```php
@foreach ($students as $stu=>$student)
  @if($loop->index < 2)
      // Your code
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

you closed the marker incorrectly. should be something like:

```php
@foreach ($students as $stu=>$student)
    @foreach ($student->FeeGroup as $key=>$FeeG)
        <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach 

    @foreach ($student->FeeGroup1 as $key1=>$FeeG1)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $FeeG1->fee_group_name }}</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach 
@endforeach 
  </tbody>
```